# weird color hue in everywhere

Tags: rendering, color

I press somewhere in rendered image and color hue is changed. I close the project and reopen it but still same. how do I fix this?

[image: after reopening]

Comment: Bloom threshold is very low.

Comment: but I cant change this in rendered image tab right? it was working firstly. but I click the image with mouse and color changed with my mouse's position. I mean when I move mouse to dark areas, rendered image became really white. but after opening it isnt worked that way. just waiting like that

Answer (score 0):

huh that is weird. I just reset the curves in color management tab with "reset" button. it worked even I set the same veriables. I guess we can use color management in rendered image. idk